# Is it possible to set the precision of the split values in scikit-learn decision trees?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

When accessing `tree_.threshold` of a node in a decision tree, the type seems to be `float`. Is there a way to set the "precision" of the thresholds to ints?
In my case, the features are all integer values so there is no need to split on values defined with such precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, scikit-learn trees use `double` type at compile time for thresholds (see https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx). A fixed data type allows to generate efficient C code. You will have to change scikit-learn source code, rebuild C extension from Cython .pyx files and then install your modified scikit-learn to use integer thresholds.

Comment: In the referenced _tree.pyx file: `from numpy import float32 as DTYPE`. So it's currently `float` not a `double`

Comment: DTYPE is a type which is used internally for input data, not a type used for threshold; if you search for 'threshold' in this file, you can see it uses double. Probably a better link could be https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fc2f24927fc37d7e42917369f17de045b14c59b5/sklearn/tree/_tree.pxd#L25